# Ubuntu VM doesn't recognize Alt-Tab anymore

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04, alt-tab

I run Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit inside a VirtualBox VM with Windows 7 Enterprise x64 as host. I just upgraded VirtualBox from 4.3.10 to 4.3.12.

I'm not entirely sure if it's due to the upgrade, but my Ubuntu VM does not recognize <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> anymore — it just inserts a Tab.

The shortcut is configured in Ubuntu under *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation*. When I try to set it again, it actually accepts the combination. But Ubuntu still does not switch.

I've tried reinstalling the Guest Additions already, no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was outlined in [this blog post](http://andrewelkins.com/linux/linux-ubuntu-12-04-alt-tab-not-working/). Essentially:

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Go to *Applications > System Tools > Preferences > Compiz Config Manager*
- Go to *Window Management* and tick the *Static Application Switcher*